# my jquery code doesnt work. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Here is my jquery code and it does not work. I really dont know why. Please help and also tell me how can I fix it.

```
$(function () {
    var panel = function () {
            var init = function () {
                console.log('hello');
            };

        return {
            init: init
        }
    };

    $('.nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
        panel.init();
    });

})();
```

I am getting this error in my console

```
Object function () {
    var panel = function () {
        var init = function () {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
} has no method 'init'
```

Comment: What does your html look like? What errors do you get?

Comment: why you have two function with the same name? "panel"

Comment: `init` is a member of `panel.panel` but not of `panel`.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake now I fixed the code but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the parentheses off of the end of the panel function declaration.

```
var panel = function () {
    var panel = function () {
        var init = function () {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
}();
```

Make sure the closing brace is followed by `()`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look on how to define a class in Javascript:

http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

```
var panel = {
    init: function () {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
}

panel.init();
```

---

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
    panel.init();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your init function is in another function panel. This is not reachable from outside.
When you want to return the init method, then you have to put the init function a level higher if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that panel should be using immediate invocation:

```
$(function () {
    var panel = (function () {
            var init = function () {
                console.log('hello');
            };

        return {
            init: init
        }
    })();

    $('.nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
        panel.init();
    });

})();
```

The code will execute imeediately and return the object to the `panel`variable. Hence `panel`picks up an `init` propertty.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do :

```
$(function () {
    var panel = {
        init: function () {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    }

    $('.nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
        panel.init();
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VAvwG/8/)

Seems more like what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this case panel is a callback, and this callback return an other callback, `init`, so you have to put () around both callback, try this:

```
$(function () {
    var panel = function () {
        var init = function () {
            console.log('hello');
        };

        return {
            init: init
        }
    };

    $('.nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
        panel().init();
    });

})();
```